# AdMob I'm seeing the same ads over and over again

Tags: android, admob

I have put an AdMob banner in my app and on my side (UK) I always see the exact same ads over and over.

When I open apps made from other dev with the exact same banner I see completely different ads. Moreover if I kill and reopen my app, the same ad that was there before killing the app is there now as well. If I do the same on these others app the ads are different, kind of they "shuffled" better.

The only thing I do my side is this on OnCreate:

```
 mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

On the AdMob page I didn't rally really do any special a part from creating the adPlacement.

Is this normal? I have seen an "mediation" option on AdMob. I this something  I want to use?

Answer (score 2):

And this will be handled by the Admob. please keep the app alive for some time and check it . also refer this.

> We recommend that you make ads persist for 60 seconds or longer,
>   depending on the functionality of the app. Our internal tests have
>   shown that this ensures users have enough time to engage with ads,
>   providing the best performance.
>
> If you choose to automatically refresh ads, make sure ad requests are
>   not made when the screen is off. Also, if users navigate to and from
>   pages with ads in an application over a short period of time, a new ad
>   request should not be made sooner than the recommended 60 second rate.

refer this for more 
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3245199?hl=en

Comment: Back then I was running an older version of the google play, I had updated to latest and the problem disappeared.. It was indeed a bug.